# Non-lishmah parchment

Tags: halacha, safrus, megillat-esther

I was learning the first two chapters of Rambam's Hilchot Megillah v'Chanukah before minchah last Shabbat. In one of the halachot of [Ch. 2](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02013.html#HtmpReportNum0094_L2):9 the Rambam discusses that megillot need not be written on klaf (or gevil) which has been made lishmah.

> וְאֵין הָעוֹר שֶׁלָּהּ צָרִיךְ לְעַבֵּד  לִשְׁמָהּ

I have two questions from this:

- Do subsequent poskim hold that a megillah need not have parchment which was made lishmah?
- What else does not require parchment which was made lishmah? (handwritten siddurim, sifrei aftarta, et c.)

Comment: "What else does not require parchment which was made lishmah? (handwritten siddurim, sifrei aftarta, et c.)" Letters to newspaper editors, shopping lists... I'm not sure what that part of your question is asking.

Comment: Shut R Meir Gavizon גאויזון (16th century egypt) #52 rules like Rambam

Answer (score 1):

MEGILLA

Shulchan Aruch, [Orach Chaim 691:1 - סימן תרצא - דיני כתיבת המגלה ותפירתה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_39.html#HtmpReportNum0005_L2) - A **Megilla** doesn't need the Klaf made Lishma; though some argue.

> **א:** אֵין כּוֹתְבִין הַמְּגִלָּה אֶלָּא בִּדְיוֹ, עַל הַגְּוִיל אוֹ עַל הַקְּלָף, כְּסֵפֶר תּוֹרָה; וְאִם כְּתָבָהּ בְּמֵי עֲפָצִים וְקַנְקַנְתּוֹם, כְּשֵׁרָה. כְּתָבָהּ בִּשְׁאָר מִינֵי צִבְעוֹנִים, פְּסוּלָה. וּצְרִיכָה  שִׁרְטוּט כַּתּוֹרָה עַצְמָהּ; **וְאֵין הָעוֹר שֶׁלָּהּ צָרִיךְ לְעַבֵּד לִשְׁמָהּ;  וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁצָּרִיךְ עִבּוּד לִשְׁמָהּ**. ‏

SEFER TORAH

Shulchan Aruch, [Yoreh De'ah 271:1 - סימן רעא - העור שנכתבה עליו ושרטוטה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_40.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L2) - A **Sefer Torah** needs the Klaf made Lishma; though a non-Jew may do the real work, after the Jew has assisted - even slightly - during the initial stages - Lishma.

> א אֵין כּוֹתְבִין סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה עַל עוֹר בְּהֵמָה, חַיָּה וְעוֹף הַטְּמֵאִים; וְלֹא עַל עוֹר דָּג, אֲפִלּוּ טָהוֹר. אֲבָל כּוֹתְבִין עַל עוֹר בְּהֵמָה, חַיָּה וְעוֹף הַטְּהוֹרִים, וַאֲפִלּוּ עוֹר נְבֵלוֹת וּטְרֵפוֹת שֶׁלָּהֶן. **וְצָרִיךְ שֶׁיְּהוּ הָעוֹרוֹת** (א) **מְעֻבָּדִין עַל יְדֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל לְשֵׁם סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה**,  שֶׁיֹּאמַר בִּתְחִלַּת הָעִבּוּד כְּשֶׁמֵּשִׂים אוֹתָם לְתוֹךְ הַסִיד: עוֹרוֹת אֵלּוּ אֲנִי מְעַבֵּד לְשֵׁם  סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה. הגה: **וְאִם מְעַבְּדָן עוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים, יְסַיַּע הַיִּשְׂרָאֵל מְעַט** (טוּר בְּשֵׁם ר''ב),  בִּתְחִלָּה כְּשֶׁנּוֹתְנוֹ לַסִּיד, וְיֹאמַר שֶׁהוּא עוֹשֶׂה לְשֵׁם קְדֻשַּׁת סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה (בֵּית יוֹסֵף), וִיסַמֵּן אוֹתָן עוֹרוֹת שֶׁלֹּא יַחֲלִיפֵן הָעוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים, וְלֹא חַיְשִׁינָן אַחַר כָּךְ שֶׁמָּא הֶחֱלִיפָן הָעוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים וְזִיֵּף סִימָנָיו אַחֲרָיו (הַגָּהוֹת מַיְמוֹנִי פֶּרֶק א' מהל' סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה) . ‏

But see the Be'er Heitev there that some argue, post-facto, if there's nothing else available, then one may use the Sefer Torah even if written on Klaf not made Lishma.

> **באר היטב**  (**א**) **מעובדין**. כתב הש''ך משמע **אם עבדו שלא לשמה אפי' בדיעבד פסול** ואפילו כתבו עליו ס''ת פסול אבל **הרא''ש והטור הביאו תשוב' הגאון שכתב** הלכך אם יש להם יכולת להחזיר יריעות הקלף לידי מתוח ולהעביר עליו סיד לשמה מה טוב ואם אין יכולת לעשות כן ואין להם ס''ת אחרת ולא קלפים אחרים **יכתבו בו אף על פי שאינו מעובד לשמה** ויקראו בה בצבור עכ''ל: ‏

TEFILLIN

Shulchan Aruch, [Orach Chaim 32:8 - סימן לב - סדר כתיבת התפלין](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_3.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L2) - **Tefillin** need the Klaf to be made Lishma. Either LeShem Tefillin or LeShem Sefer Torah.

> ח צָרִיךְ הַקְּלָף לִהְיוֹת מְעֻבָּד  בַּעֲפָצִים אוֹ בְּסִיד, וְצָרִיךְ שֶׁיְּהֵא מְעֻבָּד לִשְׁמוֹ, טוֹב לְהוֹצִיא בִּשְׂפָתָיו בִּתְחִלַּת הָעִבּוּד שֶׁהוּא **מְעַבְּדוֹ לְשֵׁם תְּפִלִּין אוֹ לְשֵׁם  סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה**, אֲבָל אִם עִבְּדוֹ לְשֵׁם מְזוּזָה פָּסוּל. ‏

And he brings a discussion what is considered Lishma - and he refers you to [11:2](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_2.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) which discusses Lishma when making Tzitzis:

> ט אִם עִבְּדוֹ עַכּוּ''ם, לְהָרַמְבָּ''ם פָּסוּל, אֲפִלּוּ אָמַר לוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל לְעַבְּדוֹ לִשְׁמוֹ, וּלְהָרֹא''שׁ כָּשֵׁר אִם יִשְׂרָאֵל עוֹמֵד עַל גַּבּוֹ וְסִיְּעוֹ: הגה: קְצָת  בְּעִבּוּדָהּ (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם הָרֹא''שׁ) וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין וְעַיֵּן לְעֵיל סִימָן י''א סָעִיף ב'. ‏

**Tefilin straps** need to be made Lishma - [סימן לג - דין תקוני התפלין ודין הרצועות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_3.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L2)

> **ג:** עוֹר הָרְצוּעוֹת צָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּהְיֶה מֵעוֹר בְּהֵמָה חַיָה וְעוֹף הַטְּהוֹרִים, וְצָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּהְיֶה מְעֻבָּד  לִשְׁמוֹ.‏

MEZUZA

Shulchan Aruch, [Yoreh De'ah 288:5 - סימן רפח - במה והיאך נכתבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_41.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) -  a **Mezuza** needs to be written on Klaf made Lishma. However, if that would prevent you from fulfilling the Mitzva, you can rely on the Rambam that you don't need Lishma.

> **ה:** **צְרִיכָה עִבּוּד לִשְׁמָהּ**, (ד) **לְכַתְּחִלָּה**. אֲבָל בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁאִם יַמְתִּין לְעוֹר מְעֻבָּד לִשְׁמָהּ יִתְבַּטֵּל מֵהַמִּצְוָה, **יִכְתְּבֶנָּה עַל עוֹר שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְעֻבָּד**, הַנִּמְצָא, (ה) וִיקַיֵּם הַמִּצְוָה מִיָּד **בְּעוֹד שֶׁמְּבַקֵּשׁ עוֹר מְעֻבָּד לִשְׁמָהּ**. ‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (ד) **לכתחלה**. ודעת רוב הפוסקים נראה **דאפי' דיעבד פסולה** בעור שאינו מעובד לשמה. כ''כ הט''ז וש''ך: (ה) **ויקיים**. כתב הש''ך דיקבענה בלא ברכה **דכדאי הם הרמב''ם וסייעתו לסמוך עליהם בשעת הדחק** דלא כמ''ש הב''ח דלא יקבענה כלל אלא יקבענה שם וישתדל להמציא אחרת כשירה עכ''ל:

Can't find anything specific - about the Klaf being made Lishma - relating to handwritten Sidurim, Sefer Haftarot or even Nevi'im written in full for the Haftara.

Comment: How do Ashkenazim hold for megillot? I checked the Aruch HaShulchan today during Shabbos and he says that there is a machloket

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - I don't know, as it's hardly relevant. We buy our Klaf at special "Sofer shops" and I wouldn't know where to find appropriate Klaf (with the lines etched in and the correct size) anywhere else.